# How do I check if the seeded data I try to create is already in my database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, dbcontext

When trying to update my database, I stumble across the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AvatarBase'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AvatarBase'. The duplicate key value is (1).
> The statement has been terminated.

I'm trying to update my database, but my `DbContext` has some seeded data in the `OnModelCreating` method that I need for when others create the database for the first time.

My `DbContext` is the following:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TurtleQuest.Models;

namespace TurtleQuest.Data
{
    public class TurtleQuestConnection : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CardMA> cardMAs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CardTORF> cardTORF { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Avatar> Avatars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }

        public TurtleQuestConnection(DbContextOptions<TurtleQuestConnection> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AvatarBase>().HasData(
            new 
            { 
                Id = 1,
                Name = "BaseImage",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Lines.png"
            }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<AvatarColor>().HasData(
            new
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Base",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Colors/base.png"
            },
            new
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Blue",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Colors/Blue.png"
            },
            new
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Purple",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Colors/Purple.png"
            },
            new
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "Red",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Colors/Red.png"
            },
            new
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "Yellow",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Colors/Yellow.png"
            }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<AvatarHat>().HasData(
            new
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Top Hat",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Accesories/Hat1.png"
            },
            new
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Cap",
                ImagePath = "/Images/Frenky/Accesories/Hat2.png"
            }
            );
        }


    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.